# Closing some activities that are running in the background

Tags: android

The application is required to close some activities that are running in the background.

For example;

Let A -> B-> C -> D Activity.

As for the E Activity after D activity, B, C, D activity kill. And in the last case;

A -> E   I want to keep activities.

I just want certain Activities to be killed.
How should I do? (Intent Flag, Keep Activity in the Stack, ActivityManager...)